# How to retrieve datetime value to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <input type="datetime" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
    <P id=firstp></P>
    <button id="button" onClick="test_function();" type="button">View</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_function(){
         $("#firstp").load("view_calls_sort.inc.php?datepicker="+ $("#datepicker").val());}
</script>
</html>
```

**view_calls_sort.inc.php:**

```
$datepicker=$_GET['datepicker'];
echo $datepicker;
```

im trying to get the datepicker value to view_calls_sort.inc.php, Above code doesn't seem to work,as an example when I input datetime like this 
2005-04-19 12:00:00.000 it is not shown in view_calls_sort.inc.php,  Can any one help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Is that exactly what your code looks like?  With your script tag outside of the HTML tag?

Comment: Where is jQuery loaded? What event triggers `test_function()` to be executed?

Comment: There also doesn't seem to be any `<form>`, so input fields won't make it back to the server.

Comment: sorry , i edited that again, there is a button and it calls the function

Comment: And the script tags still are outside of your html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding it:

```
var value = $("#datepicker").val();
$("#firstp").load("view_calls_sort.inc.php", { datepicker: value });
```

or:

```
$("#firstp").load("view_calls_sort.inc.php?datepicker=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
```

Also make sure that your `script` tag is inside your `<html>` tag and not as it is currently shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the function is called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_function(){
        alert($("#datepicker").val());
        $("#firstp").load(
            "view_calls_sort.inc.php?datepicker="+$("#datepicker").val());
    }
</script>
```

If the alert shows up, the method is called. And you get to see which value is sent to the server.

You also could change the php script and have it return a fixed value (`echo 'Foo';`) so you can see if the script is called.